# Как повесить на :disabled сразу несколько обработчиков?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, валидация

Мне необходимо повесить на кнопку 3 обработчика валидации, как это можно сделать?

```
        <button
          class="modal__button"
          type="submit"
          @click="fetchHandler"
          :disabled="!isNameValid //*тут должен быть типа + !isEmailValid*//">
        </button>
```

Comment: :disabled="!isNameValid || !isEmailValid"

Comment: Помолго, благодарю!